# How to force MOXy to use the setter on a Collection property that is lazily initialized?

Tags: eclipselink, jaxb2, moxy

Given a bean like this:

```java
public class MyBean {
    private List<Something> things;

    private List<Something> internalGetThings() {
        if (things == null) {
            things = new ArrayList<Something>();
        }
        return things;
    }

    public Iterable<Something> getThings() {
        return <an immutable copy of internalGetThings()>;
    }

    public void setThings(List<Something> someThings) {
        things.clear();
        for (Something aThing : someThings) {
            addThing(aThing);
        }
    }

    public void addThing(Something aThing) {
        things.add(aThing);
        // Do some special stuff to aThing
    }
}
```

Using external mapping file, when I map like this:

```
<xml-element java-attribute="things" name="thing" type="com.myco.Something" container-type="java.util.ArrayList" />
```

It seems that each individual Something is being added to the MyBean by calling `getThings().add()`. That's a problem because `getThings()` returns an immutable copy of the list, which is lazily initialized. How can I configure mapping (I'm using an external mapping file, not annotations) so that MOXy uses `setThings()` or `addThing()` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the reason in @Blaise's answer, it doesn't seem possible to have MOXy (or any JAXB implementation in general?) populate a lazily-initialized collection via a setter method on the collection. However, a combination of `xml-accessor-type="FIELD"` (or `@XmlAccessorType` if using annotations) and defining a [JAXB unmarshal event callback](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalEventCallback) will get the job done. In my `afterUnmarshal()` implementation I do the special work on Something instances that is done in `addSomething()`.

```java
private void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller, Object parent) {
    for (Something aThing : getSomethings()) {
        // Do special stuff on aThing
    }
}
```

Using `FIELD` access type gets JAXB/MOXy to directly inject the collection into the field, bypassing the getter. Then the call back cleans things up properly.

Answer (score 1):

### Why Does JAXB/MOXy Check the Get Method for Collection First?

JAXB (JSR-222) implementations give you a chance to have your property be the `List` interface and still leverage the underlying `List` implementation that you choose to use.  To accomplish this a JAXB implementation will call the `get` method to see if the `List` implementation has been initialized.  It it has the `List` will be populated using the `add` method.

```java
public List<String> getThings() {
    if(null == things) {
        things = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    return things;
}
```

```java
public List<String> getThings() {
    if(null == things) {
        things = new LinkedList<String>();
    }
    return things;
}
```

If you don't pre-initialize the `List` property then MOXy/JAXB will build an instance of the `List` (default is `ArrayList`) and set it on the object using the set method.

```java
private List<Something> things; // Don't Initialize

public List<String> getThings() {
    return things;
}

public void setThings(List<String> things) {
    this.things = things;
}
```

Comment: OK, I cheated a little bit in writing my question. In reality the `List` is lazily initialized using an `internalGetThings()` method (I've adjusted the code in the question above). So I was expecting the behavior you describe, but it seems to be trying `getThings()` first, not testing the actual instance field value.

Comment: @E-Riz - Same result.  In Java there is no hard link between fields and properties so JAXB/MOXy always tests (for public/property access) if a collection instance is populated via the getter.

Comment: Hmm, so if I rely on lazy initialization (which all clients of this class do, the contract of `getThings()` says that it will never return  `null` and it's an immutable copy), is there no way to do the deserialization? If I understand you correctly, I'm stumped as to how it could work at all.

Comment: By the way, I thought about using `FIELD` access for this property, but the problem is that there is special handling in `setThings()` or `addThing()` that **must** be run whenever `Something`s are added. Is there any sort of callback or other mechanism that would allow me to execute that special code after all properties have been set by MOXy? Something like [Spring's `InitializingBean`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-beans/3.2.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.java#InitializingBean)?